# How to edit scenes without loosing work in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, scene

I am creating a slide show in blender using the VSE and essentially creating a scene for each picture.

I made a mistake a few of my images and want to delete those scenes, but when I select a one scene from the dropdown list of scenes, all of the work I have complete in the VSE disappears.

If I carry on I can delete the scene, or change it ect, but I can't figure out how to get my work back in the vse without undoing, ctrl z, which of course undoes the changes I made to the scene. I'm relatively new to Blender so I'm assuming I'm doing something stupid, but I'm not even sure how to search for my answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: VSE strips are saved part of a scene, if you pick a different scene from the dropdown you will see the (empty) strip of that scene. To see your work again go back to the scene you created the strip in.

Comment: Thank you, Such a simple solution and yet now it makes perfect sense. Sometimes I feel like I'm pushing against a brick wall with Blender, but I keep learning. Thanks again.